# How can i make a more rounded UITextField? Like the search field in Safari on iPad

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitextfield, uisearchbar

HI I'm trying to get a UITextField to look like the google search field available in the safari app on iPad. The purpose of the field will be the same (a search box).

I know i could use a UISearchBar but I would have to use hackish code to get rid of the magnifying glass icon and the background and I don't want that.

I'm attaching an image with the TextField used by apple as their search box. How can I modify an UITextField to look and behave like the search field in this screenshot?
[image]

I tried to modified the UITextField's layer roundedCorners property but this doesn't work as expected.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: while playing around with roundedCorners, did you make sure that you've added the quartzcore framework as well as imported the necessary header files into your ViewController subclass?

Answer (score 17):

You can set the Corner-Radius on any UIView-Subclass.

1. Add the QuartzCore.framework to your project
2. add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your UIViewController Subclass (where you have access to the UITextfield instance of your choice
3. within viewDidLoad / viewWillAppear (or any other place where your UITextfield is allready instantiated call `[yourTextField.layer setCornerRadius:14.0f];`
4. play around with the cornerRadius value until it looks good

Comment: While this is a great method for getting rounded corners, you won't get the exact look and feel he's showing. Specifically, the shadows.

Answer (score 10):

Use the below code.It works for me:

```
searchField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,31)];
searchField.delegate = self;
searchField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
searchField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:102.0/255 alpha:1.0];
searchField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
searchField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
searchField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchField.contentVerticalAlignment =UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
searchField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
searchField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
searchField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
searchField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;        
searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
searchField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 17;
searchField.placeholder=@"Google Search";
searchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;//To change borders to rounded
searchField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; //To hide the square corners 
searchField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]; //assigning the default border color
UIBarButtonItem *searchFieldItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchField];
```

Answer (score 3):

Set background property of UITextField to an appropriate image, like this one:
[image]

Comment: In this case if alignment set to right or left, text will stand too close to the side.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a trick with making separate image of the input field you need and placing it under the real textField control. However, you will have to manipulate the colors of the textField you're placing over in order to make it transparent.

Answer (score -4):

Use a graphic with the rounded edges you want and then position a textview on top.

Comment: Thanks for response but I don't think apple used something like that when they built that functionality.